# How can I get my air ticket after having an iterenary and being issued visa?

Tags: visas, air-travel, tickets

How can I get my air ticket after having an itinerary and being issued a visa? I paid 40 pounds to get an itinerary from Schengen flight reservation visa site; applied for visa and got it. Do I pay for a new ticket now? Are the 40 pounds part of the price of the ticket? Where to buy the ticket from? This is the company: Alitalia

Comment: Which was exact site that you used? It sounds to me that this is just a site which provides fake tickets/itineraries for visa purposes. So if you want a flight, you would need to buy one at a proper airline or travel agent site.

Comment: Um... not sure that was a good move: https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/www.alitalia.com

Comment: @dunni might be on to something, but nowadays most airlines don't issue tickets, the just give you a reference number that is all you need (apart from your personal information) when you check in.

Comment: Thanks. So Alitalia not a good choice. What site do you recommend for buying an itinerary since now on, instead of this one Schengen flight reservation visa site?

Comment: @RimaMEDJEDOUB I wouldn't read much into the ratings on the page Daniil linked to. People rarely leave feedback on such sites except to complain. [Easyjet](https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/www.easyjet.com), [Lufthansa](https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/www.lufthansa.com), [Emirates](https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/www.emirates.com) and [BA](https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/www.britishairways.com) all have the same or only slightly better ratings. **If** you have a ticket from Alitalia, I don't see any reason to worry about your choice.

Comment: @RimaMEDJEDOUB but based on what you say, I suspect that dunni's comment is accurate and you don't actually have a ticket. But to get a confident answer,  you'd have to tell us which site you used.

Comment: @Daniil those ratings are always overwhelmingly bad, because annoyed customers are far more motivated to leave feedback than satisfied customers are. I've spent five minutes trying and I can't find a single airline that has more than 2 stars for their main page.

Comment: @ChrisH first airline I typed in, 2 1/2 stars: https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/www.airfrance.it

Comment: @Daniil there's a reason I explicitly said for their *main page*. airfrance.it only has 18 reviews, the uncertainties on that rating are pretty significant. But airfrance.fr, [with 505 reviews](https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/www.airfrance.fr), gets only 1.5 stars.

Comment: You shouldn't be buying an itinerary (which just says the details of a flight), you rather need to buy a ticket for a flight (which then comes with an itinerary). It seems from your description that you might have bought an itinerary for the purposes of getting a visa but didn't actually buy a plane ticket for that flight. Unless there's a miscommunication happening because English might be your second language and you have in fact bought a plane ticket. I assume you should be able to check with the airline if your booking is valid and if you will able to use it to check in for the flight?

Answer (score 8):

[Schengen Flight Reservation Visa](https://schengenflightreservationvisa.com/) provides real flight reservations for visa application purposes, but according to their FAQs,

> Our all provided itineraries are valid for up to 72 hours to up to 2 weeks time duration.

In particular, you will not be able to travel using this reservation. The 40 pounds you paid are not "part of the price of the ticket", it's just the fee that the website charges for this service. You can't get this money back or apply it toward the cost of the actual ticket.

Typically, the country you are travelling to will not require you to travel on the exact same flights you indicated when applying for the visa, so you are now free to book any flights you like on any airline, for example using a search engine like [Google Flights](https://www.google.com/flights).

If you want to avoid paying for such a service in the future, there are some options:

- If you already know which flights you want to take and are confident that your visa application will be accepted, simply book the flights that you want before applying and show the embassy the booking confirmation.
- Otherwise, you could try to find an airline that offers fully refundable tickets on your route. Then book such a fully refundable ticket and use it to apply for the visa. If the application is rejected, cancel the ticket. If the application is accepted, you can cancel the ticket and book the flights that you want, or you can choose to just keep the ticket.
  Note that not all airlines offer such fully refundable tickets, so make sure to read the terms and conditions carefully.
- A travel agent may also be able to provide an itinerary for you without buying a ticket, buy they might charge you a fee for it.

Comment: Thank you for your useful answers. kiradotee and Mophotla, please, how to avoid such a situation next time? i.e. not to buy the itinerary alone then the air ticket alone, I am expending too much money.

Comment: @RimaMEDJEDOUB I added some suggestions in my answer.